# fit an image inside div with border-radius?

Tags: html, css, border-radius

Imagine a parent `div` with a rounded `border-radius`. Is there a way to fit an `img` inside the div so that it also conforms to the rounded border?

```css
.parent-div {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <img class="image" src="/a-cool-image">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

This just results in an image with square corners while the div has rounded corners on the bottom. The only workaround I know is to have the image have the same border-radius property but only on the top two corners. I find that to be an annoying workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trying looking into a using `overflow`
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

```
.parent-div {
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 20px;

  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is a working example to showcase what I'm suggesting: https://jsfiddle.net/4mbzpfu2/3/

Comment: Thanks! I had been accidentally adding the overflow property to the child element instead of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```css
.parent-div img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.image {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround might be using *CSS*. You can set the radius property for individual corners. This is an example with rounded corners at the top, and square corners at the bottom:

```
img.yourclass { 
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

Check out this website to generate the CSS code: https://border-radius.com/